# TSX: Inline style of "padding-top" rejected: Type '{ "padding-top": string; }' is not assignable to type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

In TSX, when I specify an inline style like

```
<ModalHeading id="modal-1-heading" style={{"padding":"0px"}}>Mailing Address</ModalHeading>
```

everything works, but when I do the `padding-top` variation

```
<ModalHeading id="modal-1-heading" style={{"padding-top":"0px"}}>Mailing Address</ModalHeading>
```

I get the error

```
Type '{ "padding-top": string; }' is not assignable to type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"padding-top"' does not exist in type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'.ts(2322)
```

[image]

Sometimes this also happens with other styles like `background-color`.

Comment: Please include `ModalHeading`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide the code of the *ModalHeading* component, so I'll assume that inside the style it takes values with the *CSSProperties* type.

When you want to use such styles (for example padding-top or background-color), inside jsx/tsx inside style you need to get rid of the hyphen, instead you should use the following:

```
<ModalHeading id="modal-1-heading" style={{ paddingTop: "0px" }}>
  Mailing Address
</ModalHeading>
```

When using background-color, use the same approach - the correct name is *backgroundColor*